# Implementing a Gaussian blur kernel in MATLAB from scratch

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filter, gaussianblur

I recently implemented a box average filter in MATLAB. I found it to be a fun exercise. I wanted to do the same thing with a Gaussian blur filter, so as to eventually solve some super-resolution problems. But I have found this much more challenging. There are several questions on here about such a topic. All of the answers in those topics have been very helpful. However, I have not been able to create the kernel successfully. Currently my code simply implements an averaging filter. Wiki page for Gaussian blur: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur

Here is my code:

```
function out_im = GaussianBlur(in_im, sigma, N) %input image, sigma, Number of iterations

[rows, cols] = size(in_im);
orig_im = in_im;
Filter = zeros(rows,cols);
w2 = 0;

for k = 1 : N
    
    for LR_ROWS = 2 : 1 : rows - 1
        for LR_COLS = 2 : 1 : cols -1
            
            for i = -1 : 1
                for j = -1 : 1
                    w1 = exp(-(orig_im(LR_ROWS, LR_COLS).^2/(2*sigma^2)));
                    w2 = w2 + w1;
                    Filter(LR_ROWS, LR_COLS) = Filter(LR_ROWS, LR_COLS) + ...
                        w1*orig_im(LR_ROWS+i, LR_COLS+j);
                end
            end
            
            Filter(LR_ROWS, LR_COLS) = Filter(LR_ROWS, LR_COLS)./w2;
            w2 = 0;
        end
    end

    orig_im = Filter;
    Filter = zeros(rows, cols);
    
end

    out_im = orig_im;
end
```

Any suggestions or advice is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: So clearly I've implemented the kernel wrongly, even looking at the Wikipedia page I can see that it's not correct. But I'm not sure where to start. When performing division by the variable I call w2, w2 should be the sum of the elements in the kernel. I believe this is correctly implemented. The issue comes with what I've called w1: I'm not sure how to implement this correctly.

Comment: I don't think the pixel value `orig_im(LR_ROWS, LR_COLS)` should be inside the `exp()`. I would have thought you want to calculate your (3x3) Gaussian kernel once at the top of your function (so it's a constant 3x3 matrix). Then you basically want to index that matrix with `i` and `j` (or `i+2` and `j+2`, since `i` and `j` are `-1:1`). Then it's basically the same as your box average filter, except instead of just summing pixels, you sum the pixels multiplied by the appropriate value from your 3x3 Gaussian kernel.

Comment: Read [this old blog post of mine](https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/150) to learn a bit more about how to implement the Gaussian filter. It uses `fspecial` instead of explicitly evaluating the Gaussian function, but all the details around that are relevant to you. Especially the part about the size of the window.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments! @Cris I read through your blog post, I'll keep the kernel size at 3x3 but make sure to have a correct sigma value! If I were to choose a very high sigma, would the Gaussian blur filter lose its effect completely? From testing, if I keep sigma as very high then it performs the same as a box average filter.

Comment: @Harry, I think you're correct. I have now defined the 3x3 kernel outside of the loop. I don't quite understand how the indexing should look. But once I have this indexing for the kernel, I believe I can simply multiply this in the nested for loops (as I have already done with w1)?

Comment: Please read that blog post again. You cannot make a Gaussian in 3 pixels. You need a larger kernel. If you set sigma=0.8, the smallest you can go with it still looking like a Gaussian, you need 7 pixels across. If you make the sigma larger without making the kernel larger, you lose the Gaussian shape. In the extreme, as you indicate, you end up with a uniform kernel (box filter). Here is an example of that effect: https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/695

Comment: Agreed, a 3 by 3 kernel wouldn't have a transition region to allow for a smooth Gaussian shape. A 3 by 3 attempt at a Gaussian implementation would lead to a  weighted average that's most weighted at the centre.

Comment: @Cris Just wanted to say that your blog really helped! With your help, I was able to implement the Gaussian filter correctly. Thanks again!